# I keep getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

There is where I used the function some :

```
<span className={`icon-eye${
  moviesWatched.some(watch => watch.id === movie.id)
    ? "-blocked"
    : ""
  }`}
  onClick={() => handleChange(movie)}
/>
```

This is what's inside moviesWatched state:

```
0:{…}
id:399248
```

This is how moviesWatched gets it values:

```
handleChange= (movie) => {
  this.setState({toggleWatched:!this.state.toggleWatched}, () => this.Toggling())

  const { moviesWatched } = this.state;
  const { id } = movie;
  const _movie ={id};

  if(!moviesWatched.find(watch => watch.id === movie.id)){
    return this.setState({moviesWatched:[...moviesWatched,_movie]})
  }

  const WatchedList = moviesWatched.filter(watch => watch.id !== _movie.id)
  this.setState({moviesWatched:WatchedList})
}
```

Why is there, the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'some' of undefined

even tough `moviesWatched` isn't `undefined`?

Comment: `moviesWatched` is `undefined`, so trying to use `some` on it will give rise to your error. Could you include more of your code, so we can see where `moviesWatched` comes from?

Comment: Great. Could you show your entire component? It's still hard to see exactly what might be wrong.

Comment: What about your render method?

Comment: There's some inconsistency I see here. Is it `movieWatched` or `moviesWatched` (noice the `s`)?

Comment: How are you accessing `moviesWatched` from state?  The convention is at the top of your render method to destructure your props and state
`const { moviesWatched } = this.state;`

Comment: Oh my bad, it's moviesWatched.

Comment: const {moviesWatched} =this.props as im passing it to my other components.